# how do I pick out gaps greater than 10 in a column in unix?

Tags: unix

I have a 2 column file that I am trying to find gaps of greater than 10 in consecutive numbers:

the file is in ascending order as follows:

```
a     12

b     16

c     19

d     25

e     28

f     38

g     **40**

h     **55**

i     56

j     59

k     62
```

What I would like is to be able to print every 1st column identifier (a-k) for each occurrence where two ADJACENT numbers from the 2nd column have a value greater than 10.

For example, the output I am looking for here is: **g, h** 
(as the difference between the 2nd column associated with g and h is greater than 10)

Would very much appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, using `perl`, `awk`, or even only a shell script, e. g.:

```
while read ID num
do  if expr "$num" - "$prenum" ">" 10 >/dev/null 2>&1   # discard expr output
    then    echo $preID, $ID
    fi
    preID=$ID prenum=$num
done <2_column_file # your 2 column file
```

I assumed your *2 column file* doesn't actually contain empty lines, but rather the above are artifacts of SO formatting problems (you could have used ```` ``` ```` lines around).

Comment: Hi thanks so much for this. I am new to UNIX would you be able to give me an example with my 2col file named waheed.txt for example, how should this be incorporated into your code? Thank you!

Comment: @Waheed Ahmed - To incorporate a file waheed.txt, just change the last line `done <2_column_file` to `done <waheed.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk ' { c=$2; if(c-p>10 && NR>1 ) { print a,p; print $0 } p=c;a=$1 } '
```

with inputs

```
$ awk ' { c=$2; if(c-p>10 && NR>1 ) { print a,p; print $0 } p=c;a=$1 } ' waheed.txt
g 40
h 55

$ cat waheed.txt
a 12
b 16
c 19
d 25
e 28
f 38
g 40
h 55
i 56
j 59
k 62

$
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help, what if the file was a 10 column file and I wanted to look for jumps of 500 from two CONSECUTIVE rows between the third column and I wanted the output to be the two adjacent column 1 row where the jump between the two adjacent rows is 500. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense :)